# Most barebones MongoDB Express.js app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

What is the simplest MongoDB using app possible using express.js? I don't want anything fancy. I basically just need a way to add things to a DB and query it later. What's the simplest way to do this? Please answer this as if I was a toddler. I'm used to the simple workflow of Meteor apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way, which can be very messy, is to use express.js, import the mongo module and do the insert/querying.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, dba) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
  db = dba;
});

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  db.collection('test').insert({name: 'Peter'}, function(err, result) { res.send(result); });

});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Comment: Do I have to have a DB at `mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb` first? Also how does it recognize `db` without a proper declaration?

Comment: if there's no need of authentication in your mongo installation, it will create it automatically. The db will be undefined until the mongo connects.

Comment: This error came up in my console: `{ [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED] name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }`

Comment: Do you have mongoDB installed and running locally? if yes, does it have credentials?

Comment: just type `mongo` in your console. If does not connect, I would suggest you to install it. Since you asked to use mongo, I thought you already had it. You can google for tutorials on how to install mongo in various platform (is very straight forward)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89527/discussion-between-isaac-wasserman-and-devalien).